# For loop only displays last data retrieved from firebase

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

I have this for loop where I retrieve user's progress

Typescript:

```
his.userProgress = af.object('/UserProgress/' + this.currentUser + '/', { preserveSnapshot: true });

    this.userProgress.subscribe(snapshots => {
        snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
            this.userScores.push(snapshot.val());
        });
        console.log(this.userScores);

        //set this one to i<=8 because total no. of quizzes are 9. which means this.userScores.length -1
        for(var i=0; i <= 8; i++){
            if (this.userScores.length == i) {
                this.scores = [{
                    None: "Nothing Recorded"
                }];
                console.log("Nothing");
            }

            else if (this.userScores.length >= i) {
                this.scores = [{
                    Chapter:this.userScores[i].Chapter_Quiz,
                    QuizNo:this.userScores[i].Quiz,
                    Score:this.userScores[i].Score,
                }];
                console.log("With Scores");
            }
        }

    });
```

First, it will check if there is the userScores[] length is less 0 or greater than or equal 0. If there is no score for that quiz, it will display "Nothing Recorded" else it will display the score.

HTML:

```
<ion-card>

<ion-list *ngFor="let score of scores">
  <ion-card-header>
    {{score.Chapter}}
  </ion-card-header>

  <button ion-item *ngIf="scores.length < 0">
    <ion-icon name="planet" item-start></ion-icon>
    {{score.None}}
  </button>

  <button ion-item *ngIf="scores.length >= 0">
    <ion-icon name="planet" item-start></ion-icon>
    {{score.Score}}
  </button>

</ion-list>
```

I'm having problems where it only displays the last record. What is am I doing wrong?

[image: Displays MitAdapt only on my View]

Expected Output:

```
If finished with the 1st quiz:

1st: Score
2nd: Nothing Recorded
3rd: Nothing Recorded
....


if no score at all:
1st: Nothing Recorded
2nd: Nothing Recorded
.....
```

Comment: which one of the log shows?

Comment: @Vega it only displays MitAdapt. I added the output from my console.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in every iteration of the loop, you are changing the value in the  `this.scores` variable when in fact you should be pushing it to store the data from the previous quizzes.

Use `this.scores.push` instead.

You could also change the condition in the for-loop and use `i < this.userScores.length` to make it depend on the length of the array.

Then change the `ngIf` in the html to check if `score.Score` exists or not. If it doesn't, there's no score

Answer (score 0):

Well, from your code it seems like `this.userScores.length = 9` is always greater than the index `i` within the loop (`i` only varies from `0` to `8`). So for each loop iteration the last block (`else if` block) gets executed. Since you are not dynamically changing/adding to the `this.scores` array but only assigning to the object itself (not changing the array index for `this.scores` somehow or pushing to the existing `this.scores` list), the value in the current iteration of `this. userScores[i]`'s index gets stored to `this.scores` at each iteration. Upon the last iteration, whatever the `this.userScores[8]` had will be the value of `this.scores` with that list only having `length = 1`.

Makes sense?